# $\mathbb{R}^{13}$ has two subspaces such that dim(S)=7 and dim(T)=8 <br/>

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\mathbb{R}^{13}$ has two subspaces such that dim(S)=7 and dim(T)=8

⒜ max dim (S∩T)=?
⒝ min dim (S∩T)=?
⒞ max dim (S+T)=?
⒟ min dim (S+T)=?
⒠ dim(S∩T) + dim (S+T)=?

Comment: You would want to first state Rank-Nullity theorem, and see how you can apply it to the problem at hand.

Comment: To add onto @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг comment, considering writing out arbitrary bases for each subspace, and seeing how those bases "interact" in each scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended hint:

Most of these can be worked out rather intuitively just from one's intuition in lower dimensions. For example, if $S \subset T$, then the dimension of $S \cap T$ is just the dimension of $T$ - nothing new is added. This is pretty clearly a minimal situation. What should you do to make them as large as possible? How large can they be?

Recall that $S+T$ is the set of sums of a vector in $S$ and a vector in $T$. In situations similar to the ones we just thought about, what happens with these dimensions? Are these maximal and minimal?

Finally (e) asks you to think about the relationship between these two operations. If $S$ and $T$ overlap more, the intersection gets bigger. What does this mean about the amount of stuff you can express as a combination of one vector from each part?

To run with these ideas, try working in a basis in low dimensions, and then just replace your dimension with $n$, so that it works in general.

Comment: Is the answer 7, 2, 13, 7, 15?

Answer (score 3):

I think your teacher wants that you use the following theorem:

Let $S, T$ two subspaces of a vectorial space $R$ then $dim(S)+dim(T)=dim(S∩T)+dim(S+T)$

So please, feel free to compute the max and the min with this formula.

PD: Note that the max dimension of the intersection is $min(dim(S),dim(T))$

Moreover, in this case the max dimension of the sum is $13$ because $8+7>13$

PD2: The dimension can't exceed the dimension of the vectorial space $R$

Comment: What does min(S,T) denote?

Comment: @Kyotomath fixed, thank you :)

Comment: Is the answer 7, 2, 13, 7, 15?